# In pandas/python, reading array stored as string

Tags: python, arrays, csv, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe where one of the columns has array of strings as each element.

So something like this.

```
  col1 col2
0 120  ['abc', 'def']
1 130  ['ghi', 'klm']
```

Now when i store this to csv using to_csv it seems fine.
When i read it back using from_csv i seems to read back. 
But then when i analyse the value in each cell the array is

'[' ''' 'a' 'b' 'c' and so on. 
So essentially its not reading it as an array but a set of strings. Can somebody suggest how I can convert this string into an array?

I mean to say the array has been stored like a string

```
'[\'abc\',\'def\']'
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As mentioned in the other questions, you should use `literal_eval` here:

```
from ast import literal_eval
df['col2'] = df['col2'].apply(literal_eval)
```

In action:

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([[120, '[\'abc\',\'def\']'], [130, '[\'ghi\',\'klm\']']], columns=['A', 'B'])

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
     A              B
0  120  ['abc','def']
1  130  ['ghi','klm']

In [13]: df.loc[0, 'B']  # a string
Out[13]: "['abc','def']"

In [14]: df.B = df.B.apply(literal_eval)

In [15]: df.loc[0, 'B']  # now it's a list
Out[15]: ['abc', 'def']
```

Comment: Can I get some explanation how literal_eval is working for the mentioned problem?

Comment: @HammadHassan it tries to parse a string into a python object, similar to json.loads.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is slower than using pandas own `split` function -- see the answer below.

Answer (score 6):

Nevermind got it.

All i had to do was

```
arr = s[1:-1].split(',')
```

This got rid of the square brackets and also split the string into an array like I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Without pandas, this is one way to do it using the `ast` modules' `literal_eval()`:

```
>>> data = "['abc', 'def']"
>>> import ast
>>> a_list = ast.literal_eval(data)
>>> type(a_list)
<class 'list'>
>>> a_list[0]
'abc'
```

Comment: with pandas, you should also use `literal_eval`!

Comment: @AndyHayden Ah okay! Never used pandas, wouldn't know :)

Comment: this is more what i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using a different separator value? Like so:

```
DataFrame.to_csv(filepath, sep=';')
```

and then read with

```
DataFrame.from_csv(filepath, sep=';')
```