# Python: save pandas data frame as .csv keeping its original attributes

Tags: python, csv, dataframe

Hello I generated a dataframe `df` that looks like the following

[image]

Where `car`, `time` and `val` array arrays. I saved this dataframe as

```
df.to_csv('MyData/data.csv')
```

However when I upload it the columns `car`, `time` and `val` are strings. Is there any way to keep the columns as arrays?

Comment: Can you show what the first few lines of the output looks like, and how you would like it to look?

Comment: I think you're going to run into issues due to the file format. It's a CSV, so if any field has commas then you have enclose it in quotes. If it didn't do this, there would be no way of distinguishing two separate columns and one with commas it in

Comment: When I upload the file, the entry is like `df.val[0] = '[ 14.50980392  14.11764706  14.50980392 ...,  14.50980392  14.11764706\n  14.50980392]'` which is a string of `char` and I would like  `df.val[0]= array([ 14.50980392,  14.11764706,  14.50980392, ...,  14.50980392,
        14.11764706,  14.50980392])` as in the original table

Comment: Could you please edit the question to include this information?

Comment: If you just want to save the data frame so you can load it again, you would be better saving it to a different format. Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17098654/how-to-store-data-frame-using-pandas-python

Comment: If it has to be a csv, the issue here isn't the saving, but how the file is being parsed when it's read (this is what you mean by 'upload', right?).
In this case, I think this may help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23119472/in-pandas-python-reading-array-stored-as-string?rq=1

Comment: It has not be a `.csv`. You solved my issue!