# How to read an array in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a tsv file containing an array which has been read using `read_csv()`.

The dtype of the array is shown as `dtype: object`. How do I read it and access it as an array?

For example:

```
df=

id   values
1    [0,1,0,3,5]
2    [0,0,2,3,4]
3    [1,1,0,2,3]
4    [2,4,0,3,5]
5    [3,5,0,3,5]
```

Currently I am unpacking it as below:

```
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    string = row['col2']
    string=string.replace('[',"")
    string=string.replace(']',"")
    v1,v2,v3,v4,v5=string.split(",")
    v1=int(v1)
    v2=int(v2)
    v3=int(v3)
    v4=int(v4)
    v5=int(v5)
```

Is there any alternative to this?

I want to do this because I want to create another column in the dataframe taking the average of all the values.

Adding additional details:col2

My tsv file looks as below:

```
id   values
1    [0,1,0,3,5]
2    [0,0,2,3,4]
3    [1,1,0,2,3]
4    [2,4,0,3,5]
5    [3,5,0,3,5]
```

I am reading the tsv file as follows:
`df=pd.read_csv('tsv_file_name.tsv',sep='\t', header=0)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In pandas/python, reading array stored as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23119472/in-pandas-python-reading-array-stored-as-string)

Comment: could you show an example of the CSV file and what exact code do you use to load it as dataframe? I have the impression that with setting up the separator (and possibly a little preprocessing) you could do this in a much cleaner way

Comment: Okay, will add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `json` to simplify your parsing:

```
import json
df['col2'] = df.col2.apply(lambda t: json.loads(t))
```

*edit*: following your comment, getting the average is easy:

```
# using numpy
df['col2_mean'] df.col2.apply(lambda t: np.array(t).mean())
# by hand
df['col2_mean'] df.col2.apply(lambda t: sum(t)/len(t))
```

Comment: Is there further way such that we can get the average of the elements?

Comment: It works, thanks for showing the use of lambda, I am even able to apply the desired operations. I wanted a weighted average, I am able to apply the weights and do it. Thank you,.

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv

with open('myfile.tsv) as tsvfile:
    line = csv.reader(tsvfile, delimiter='...')
    ...
```

OR

```
from pandas import DataFrame

df = DataFrame.from_csv("myfile.tsv", sep="...")
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.