# Return dataframe rows for a specific integer search

Tags: python, dataframe

I would like to return a filtered dataframe that does NOT contain a specific integer, like 2.  However, it does need to return rows that have integers like 12, or 22, or 200...etc.

Example:

```py
d = {'num_list': ["1,2,3,10,11,12,13","","4,5,6","11,12,13","2,3,4,12","12,13"]}
searchfor = "2"

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

filtered_df = df[~df['num_list'].str.contains(searchfor)]
```

The dataframe:

```py
                num_list
0      1,2,3,10,11,12,13
1
2                  4,5,6
3               11,12,13
4               2,3,4,12
5                  12,13
```

Expected result:

```py
                num_list
1
2                  4,5,6
3               11,12,13
5                  12,13
```

Actual result:

```py
                num_list
1
2                  4,5,6
```

This code is matching the string "2" which also exists in row 3 and 5.  Trying to find the right method to solve this.  I'm thinking of changing colum num_list to a list, but I don't know how to filter a dataframe list.

```py
d = {'num_list': [[1,2,3,10,11,12,13],[],[4,5,6],[11,12,13],[2,3,4,12],[12,13]]}
searchfor = 2

df = pd.DataFrome(data=d)

??
```

The dataframe:

```py
                   num_list
0 [1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12, 13]
1                        []
2                 [4, 5, 6]
3              [11, 12, 13]
4             [2, 3, 4, 12]
5                  [12, 13]
```

Is this the right approach?  How do I return rows that does not have the specific integer 2 (i.e. return row 1,2,3,5)?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested [in this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41518959/3628578), you can use a mask and the `apply` function to solve your problem statement.

```
d = {'num_list': [[1,2,3,10,11,12,13],[],[4,5,6],[11,12,13],[2,3,4,12],[12,13]]}
searchfor = 2
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

# Here we create our mask that is essentially a list of True and False for
# each row on which the condition applies. 
mask = df.num_list.apply(lambda x: searchfor not in x)

# Now we can apply the mask to df
df_filtered = df[mask]
```

Unfiltered DataFrame:

```
>>> df
                    num_list
0  [1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12, 13]
1                         []
2                  [4, 5, 6]
3               [11, 12, 13]
4              [2, 3, 4, 12]
5                   [12, 13]
```

And the result of `df_filtered` now contains all rows except the ones that consist of the value in `searchfor`:

```
>>> df_filtered
    num_list
1            []
2     [4, 5, 6]
3  [11, 12, 13]
5      [12, 13]
```

Comment: When reading in the dataframe from a file, I also had to convert num_list column from a string to a list and I found this handy.  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23119472/11985313)

Comment: Great, thanks for sharing! If my answer worked please don't forget to accept it :)